# Getting random crashes while pushing to another view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, crash

I am getting random crashes while pushing to another view controller. 
 
It was too difficult to find out such a crash, we spent the almost 2-3 days to solve this issue. seems like the crash was due to the one extra view outlet got connected to the main view in the storyboard. Which created the nil reference for some objects of the view controller and applications crashes. 
But something surprising to us that how Xcode allowing me to connect the two outlets to the main view. I have again tried connecting the same but this time it is not allowing me to connect.  Attaching the screenshot for the same. 
 
Any kind of help/explanation is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Try to reconnect that. If you have copy paste something from other project / Storyboard this may happen sometime

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Thanks for the reply, but I didn't copy anything, I don't know, how that extra outlet added? I solved my issue by removing that but worried why that happened.

Comment: Please add the crash logs for more info. Crashes can be caused by many different reasons.

Comment: can you please give access to your code

Comment: Can you please add crash message/log you are getting? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add crash logs. We should check them. Theres any data moving between two ViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with Xcode sometimes while editing the outlets.Find the controller on which app crashes and reconnect the outlets and run again.I don't know the exact reason but that solve my problem.